# How can I extend restrictions on simple type element?

Tags: xsd

Could somebody post an example about how to add enumerated restriction on simpletype element in xml schema?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
  <xs:simpleType name="myElement">
    <xs:union memberTypes="previousRestrictions">
      <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
          <xs:enumeration value="close" />
        </xs:restriction>
      </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:union>
  </xs:simpleType>
```

Answer (score 1):

In this example, the `fruit` element must be a string whose value is in the set `{"apple", "banana", "coconut"}`.

```
<xs:element name="fruit">
  <xs:simpleType>
   <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value="apple"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="banana"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="coconut"/>
   </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

So, this is valid:

```
<fruit>banana</fruit>
```

but this is not:

```
<fruit>kumquat</fruit>
```